# How do I find LDS digital file 4548813?

Tags: census-records, scotland, digitization

I called the Family History Library in Salt Lake City to ask about an index for the film #1042404 - 1851 [Scotland, Ayrshire, Kilmarnock - Census](https://www.familysearch.org/search/catalog/634269), and they told me that they have the film, but that it has also been digitized. They gave me the number for the digitized file #4548813, but the person couldn't remember how to access this online. He said that it should be accessible outside of the library and it should be open for everyone to access.

Does anyone know how to access this digital file?

Answer (score 5):

In general, to see what image sets have been released on familysearch.org for a particular country, go to the bottom of the home page, click on a region, such as "United Kingdom and Ireland". This will show a list of collections. The collections that show a camera to the left of the title have images available, sometimes on a different web site. Some of the collections have indexes and some are browse only.

In your case, at the time I write this there doesn't appear to be images available for the 1851 Scottish Census.

[United Kingdom and Ireland](https://www.familysearch.org/search/collection/list#page=1&region=UNITED_KINGDOM_IRELAND)

Answer (score 4):

I am fairly certain that the licensing for the Scottish censuses does not allow anyone to access images online other than through ScotlandsPeople, a pay-to-view site - their PPV site. Within an LDS Library / Centre may be a different matter, if the LDS filmed the censuses.

Comment: hmm... It was and LDS elder at the Library that told me about the digital file. He said that it should be accessible outside of the library, but I'll double check.

Comment: My interpretation of the info at the FamilySearch site is that the census films in question were produced by the LDS; there are two separate filmings.

Answer (score 2):

Following up on the previous attempts:

1. **Searching the Catalog** -- Putting 4548813 in the field **Film/Fiche Number** resulted in four catalog entries, one of which is **Census returns for Kilmarnock (parish 597), 1841-1891**, linked to in the question.  The film notes show the two different filmings and notes that one series of films should be consulted before requesting the films in the other series be pulled from the Vault.  If these were available to online viewers, outside a FHC or the FHL, there should be a statement to that effect in a red font, as we determined in the question [Which FHL microfilms are available to view online?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/3883/1006); this was also confirmed by David Dilts in a recent live webinar on Using the Family History Catalog (no recording was made).
2. Searching Records -- Putting the number 4548813 into the **Film Number** field brings up 16,766 results for Film Number:4548813. The results are an index only, with no camera icons displayed on the right.  This agrees with what we were told in the online webinar on **Scotland Census Records** which was part of the intermediate series of classes on Scotland Research given in May 2015.  The handouts and recording of this webinar (and others) can be accessed via the FamilySearch Wiki on the page [Family History Library Classes and Webinars](https://familysearch.org/learn/wiki/en/Family_History_Library_Classes_and_Webinars).  There have been some technical problems lately with wiki article links dumping the viewer at the main page for FamilySearch.org -- if this link does not go directly to the page, enter the Wiki first, then enter the article title in the search box on the right-hand side of the page.
3. Digital Image Files -- catalog entries:

When searching Devon Baptisms, I saw an entry whose abstract had a Digital Folder Number.  On the right hand side, the screen looks like this:

[image]

Searching the catalog for that folder number in the Film number field brings up the catalog entry, which has this notation:

[image]

I was signed in, but I do not have an LDS account.  Perhaps the consultants at the FHC can see the images on their accounts no matter where they are, but those of us with non-LDS accounts can only view them at the FHC/FHL.

---

I am wondering if some of these digital files are not available remotely because of rights issues or privacy issues.

Added 16 Feb 2016: [England, Devon Bishop's Transcripts, 1558-1887](https://familysearch.org/search/collection/2515875?collectionNameFilter=false)

Browsing the collection brings you to a page of [waypoints](https://familysearch.org/search/image/index#uri=https://familysearch.org/recapi/sord/collection/2515875/waypoints) that appear to be digital file numbers.

Clicking one of the number gives me a popup with this message, whether or not I am already logged in.

[image]

If I am not logged in, I log in and then get dumped back at the home page.

If I click on a person's name instead, when I get to the details I see this on the right:

[image]

Since the images were posted today, it seems likely that they haven't yet linked the images to the index yet. But as of today, I don't see an explicit message that you have to be at the FHL/FHC on the individual search results, nor do I see the red "to view the digital images click here" message on the catalog entry.