# Finding online resource for searching Italian records?

Tags: census-records, birth-records, marriage-records, death-records, italy

From ancestry.co.uk I know I have an Italian Great-Great Grandmother, name Maude Angelina Georgina Antonio, born 1880 Milano, Italy, father Thomas Antonio, married William Elias Barnett in 1899, Greenhill England.

I would like to find more about her parents, likely to both be Italian.

Who provides searchable Italian records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think a starting point could be the [Catalog of FamilySearch.org](https://familysearch.org/catalog/search):

[image]

This will lead you to a [page of information about Italian records](https://familysearch.org/search/catalog/results?count=20&placeId=98&query=%2Bplace%3AItaly):

[image]

As commented by @JanMurphy:

> In the screenshot above, the drop-down box can be set to any local
>   family history center, the Family History Library, or "online" to show
>   which FHL records can be accessed via the website.  See
>   https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/3886/1006

[image]

... and more information from another comment by @JanMurphy:

> See Joni Kessler's class handout "[Using the FamilySearch Catalog
>   Effectively](https://familysearch.org/learn/wiki/en/images/7/70/Using_the_FamilySearch_Catalog_Effectively.pdf)" which is available for download ...  Users
>   should also check the drop-down box to see if their local FHC is in
>   the list -- if so they can browse the catalog of their local center
>   before leaving home.  Most of the FHC/FHLs are in the US but some
>   international sites are being added to the list (as I write this, I
>   see London and Taipei).

Comment: In the screenshot above, the drop-down box can be set to any local family history center, the Family History Library, or "online" to show which FHL records can be accessed via the website.  See http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/3886/1006

Comment: Thanks @JanMurphy - rarely a day goes by when I don't learn something new from you :-)

Comment: See Joni Kessler's class handout "Using the FamilySearch
Catalog Effectively" which is available for download: https://familysearch.org/learn/wiki/en/images/7/70/Using_the_FamilySearch_Catalog_Effectively.pdf (the link to the handout is also in my answer linked to above).  Users should also check the drop-down box to see if their local FHC is in the list -- if so they can browse the catalog of their local center before leaving home.  Most of the FHC/FHLs are in the US but some international sites are being added to the list (as I write this, I see London and Taipei).

Comment: Okay I did what you said, the list of online records in included church Baptisms but unfortunately I could get no hit. There was no listing for census records however - that is what I really looking for, are they available anywhere ?

Comment: Would you be able to ask that as a new and more specific question, please?  That way this Q&A can remain as a general introduction to Italian records.

Comment: ok done http://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/10124/is-there-an-online-resource-for-searching-italian-census-records

Answer (score 1):

I recomend you to search in [antenati.san.beniculturali.it](http://www.antenati.san.beniculturali.it/)

I found there my 6th upper ancestor

Have records of birth, marriage, death and other kind of records digitalized (some of them indexed so you can search on them) It begin in the early 1800s up to 1900

PD: This is one of the sources of familysearch.org