# Is there an online resource for searching Italian census records

Tags: census-records, italy

From ancestry.co.uk I know I have an Italian Great-Great Grandmother, name Maude Angelina Georgina Antonio, born 1880 Milano, Italy, father Thomas Antonio, married William Elias Barnett in 1899, Greenhill England.

I would like to find more about her parents, likely to both be Italian. For Uk research Ive found census records invaluable. I know they did censues in Italy but are they publicably available (online)

Comment: Its not a duplicate because this question specifically asks for an online search the linked question does not

Comment: The linked question asks for online [or] offline Italian census information, and most of its answers include online resources.

Comment: @PaulTaylor We had a similar question earlier when someone asked for free resources.  See http://meta.genealogy.stackexchange.com/q/2057/1006.  In my opinion, it's easier to have one question and one set of answers, and divide each answer into online resources and offline resources.  People are more likely to find the information if all of the answers are in one place, and it's easier to update the answers as specific collections are placed online.

Comment: I dont mind having the answer in one place, but its useful to have multiple questions to one answer because I didnt find that answer when I searched for it before posting question